# Creating an unknown amount of Strings of fixed length in C?

Tags: arrays, string, performance, char

I am trying to create an unknown amount of strings of length 80.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

  char str[81];
  readIn(str);

  return 0;
}

void readIn(char arr[])
{
  int k=0;
  while ((arr[k] = getchar()) != '\n')
  {
    k++;
  }
}
```

I want my readIn function to loop and store each loop as a new string until the user enters an empty string. I was thinking 2-dimensional array (one for length of string and one for number of strings), but even then there needs to be a fixed amount of both dimensions.

I'm open to any solutions.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may use dynamical allocation to increase the size of an array as needed. Do this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// (!) readIn is not safe (the user may input more than 79 characters per line)
// also, the program may crash if the user types an end-of-input (ctrl-D)
void readIn(char *arr) {
  int k;
  for (k = 0; (arr[k] = getchar()) != '\n'; ++k) ;
  arr[k] = '\0'; // end-of-string character
}

...

int alloc = 2; // capacity of the array of strings
int length; // current position in the array of strings (and finally length)
char **strArray = calloc(alloc, sizeof(char *)); // array of strings

for (length = 0; ; ++length) {
  if (length >= alloc) { // increase the size if necessary
    alloc *= 2; // doubles the allocated space
    strArray = realloc(strArray, alloc * sizeof(char *));
  }
  strArray[length] = calloc(80, sizeof(char)); // allocates string of length 80
  readIn(strArray[length]);
  if (strArray[length][0] == '\0') // if the first character is end-of-string, the string is empty
    break; // go out from the cycle
}
// now "length" contains the length of strArray

...
```

Answer (score -1):

Dynamically sized arrays in C are tough.  But to create an array of strings, it is simple:

```
char arrayOfStrings[Number of Strings][Length of Each String];
```

---

```
char arrayOfStrings[100][80];
strcpy(arrayOfStrings[0], "String Number One");
strcpy(arrayOfStrings[1], "String Number Two");
```

---

```
void readIn(char arrayOfStrings[][])
{
    int i = 0;
    int ii = 0;
    while (arrayOfStrings[ii][0] != '\n' && ii <= 100) // Just an 'Enter'
        i = 0;
        while ((arrayOfStrings[ii][i] = getchar()) != '\n' && i <= 80)
        {
            i++;
        }
        ii++;
    }
}
```